# Почему xml для android такой ужасный на вид и есть ли альтернативы?

Tags: android, xml

Начал проходить курс по андроиду и был неприятно удивлен xml-коду для описания визуальной части. код, как на меня вызывает крайне стремное ощущения - мешанина camel case и snake case. отдельные атрибуты являются фактически составными полями. логика формирования названий крайне загадочна. это лишь у меня такие ощущения или у других тоже оно возникало? Есть ли альтернативы позволяющие писать на чем-то более адекватном?

Comment: На самом деле там всё логично и понятно. Дело времени. Надо привыкнуть. Только не пользуйтесь визуальным эдитором

Comment: пока у меня тоже возникло ощущения, что создатели хмл-я надеялись что никто в создаваемый код смотреть не будет

Comment: Начинал программировать под андроид. Всё в xml логично и нормально. Лично для меня похожий HTML как раз таки ужасен и нелогичен. А различия в написании, как я понимаю, историческая проблема обратной совместимости. Со временем должна будет снизиться.

Comment: HTML тоже ужасен, нужен JSON/QML :)

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативы всегда есть. Самое простое - не смотрите в `xml`, а используйте `Android layout editor`.

Можете прямо в коде создавать все элементы и размещать их.

А можете немного привыкнуть и первое "стремное" ощущение пройдет, а в многих вещах даже найдете их логичность.

Comment: звучит почти как девиз садомазохиста